# Why does the search image in my code doesn't work?

Tags: python, pyautogui, python-3.9

This is my code:

```
 import pyautogui


images = ['colordonkergrijsDCphrasev2.png'] #the image I want it to find
while True:
  for image in images: #search for the image in images
    pos = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, region=(740,870, 50, 20)) #search on the screen for the image
    if pos is not None: # this checks that the image was found   
      pyautogui.click(pos) # click the position of the image
```

I want that my code clicks on a special region when he is seeing that image.
But my code doesn't do that, my code clicks every time also when the image isn't there. The image I'm using is very similar as the background. But I added `confidence = 1` and it still doesn't work
Does someone know how to fix it?
I use Python 3.9.4 64-bit.
I already read the docs but there isn't anything in there what can help me.
If you want to docs here it is: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

Comment: can you add further information about your environment (e.g. operating system e.t.c) your code works for me. I verified it with windows calculator and its buttons.

Comment: Yes, so if you replace that image with yours does it work? Because mine doesn't. The operating system is windows 64-bit.

Comment: yes - exactly. if I replace it with my image it does work. (windows 10, 64 bit)

Comment: Thanks for your reaction but mine still doesn't work. The image I'm using is an image that is very similar to the background. Probably is that the problem. But if I add confidence = 1, it doesn't click either that the image is still there. Any suggestions? I'm using VScode btw.

Comment: okay. can you confirm that you have open cv installed? You need to have OpenCV installed for the confidence keyword to work.